# My snake has yellow/green patch on stomach and has sadly passed away, what is it?

Tags: snakes

This morning my brother sadly found his pet snake dead; he had noticed this yellow/green patch on his stomach and has no clue what it is as it wasn’t there before. The snake hadn’t been eating properly for a few weeks. Does anyone know what this is?

> [image]

Comment: If it was not eating, did you visited or called a vet?

Comment: It would be useful for answering your question, to get possible informations of a vet visit.

Comment: If I should guess, I would assume, that it was a egg bound female, or that it i not digest the food in the right way. But I am not a snake expert, so it will stay a guess. Did the snake shed in the past 2 to 5 weeks?

Comment: I just had a small garter snake die the same way, it hasn't been eating and was obviously starving, I had to force feed it and 4 others yesterday, the rest are doing fine but this guy didn't make it. I don't think it's scale rot, I have a dozen and the rest are fine. Many people think it's bile leaked from the gall bladder, but I'm no vet and cannot confirm that. Maybe they got something like a piece of substrate stuck in their gut that caused problems? https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hCvl.jpg

Comment: This is due to dehydration from someone who works with reptiles